# Стили и разметка

Tags: html, css

Нашёл на просторах интересную библиотеку стилей к framework'у `bootstrap 4`
И заинтересовало меню от туда, но возникла проблема там 20к строк кода и вручную искать нужные стили к классам займёт уйму времени, а тянуть всю эту библиотеку - бред.

Собственно вопрос, есть ли какие нибудь инструменты, которые помогут вытянуть все нужные стили к классам?

Comment: Поиск в текстовом редакторе. Обычно (`Ctrl + F`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У bootstrap есть сборщик. Вы можете собрать необходимые компоненты и сделать сборку для себя или подключать к своему проекту необходимые файлы.

https://itchief.ru/bootstrap/build-project-with-gulp-v4

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего таких инструментов нет, да и ни к чему они.. такие библиотеки ориентированы на полное их использование. 
Вообще если есть желание играться - можно тянуть стили из браузера, сначала создав елемент, потом открываем страничку и смотрим какие стили зайдействованы к конкретному елементу страницы

Comment: Не все псевдоклассы отображаются в браузере... В этом и проблема

Comment: @Алексей  вообще то все псевдо классы отображаются